# Android - In-app billing from user's bank details

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have to develop an app implementing in-app purchase, whoses purchases are suscriptions to a service (with a fixed price).

My client didn't ask me to use *Google's in-app billing API*, and asked me to provide fields for the user to enter his bank details instead (and to directly interact with banks I guess). I haven't seen many apps doing this (except maybe *Uber*), and I'm wondering what am I supposed to do.

Should I tell him to use *Google's in-app billing API* instead ?
Or should I develop this from scratch / using a library ? (I really don't feel confident about this...)

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a bad idea.  I certainly would immediately uninstall any app that asked for my bank account information.  If it were me I would try to convince the client to go with Google's service, or at least some trusted third party - does Amazon have an in app purchase system for Android?  I've only used Google's.  That system is set up to allow purchases without giving credit card or bank information to the app.  It may even be a violation of Android developer terms to ask for banking information, you may want to look into that.

Have they given you any reasons why they don't want to use the Google service?  Is it possible they just don't know about it?